# Fluentd - how to access logs in user home directory

Tags: logging, fluentd, td-agent

I have been install fluentd on my company servers to transfer the logs to Newrelic. I'm using Fluentd because the disto on the server is Amazon Linux 1 and newrelic agent doesnt support log fowarding in that version(if you wondered).

The logs is under the following folder: /home/ec2-user/app/logs/main.log
I dont think this is the best practice but this is how it is right now. td-agent gives me error about permission to this log file because the ec2-user doesn't have a persmission to the folder to others or groups because if i change it i could not access to the ssh afterwards. I also tried symlink but of course it wont make sense if it worked.

Please help to tuckle this :)

Comment: `fluentd` is running under different `user:group`?

Comment: im running with td-agent